# Using createMuiTheme to override default styles on div's, p's, body

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

This is perhaps a simple Material UI Theme Customization question.

What I want to do is to override the default styling on `<body>` (and other common tags in the future). Right now at the root of my React tree:

```
import theme from './mui-theme'


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StylesProvider injectFirst>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <App />
      </StylesProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

There's a theme that specifies some things but leaves out `'body1'`

`const theme = useTheme()` and `console.log(theme)` shows that it is defined as:

```
typography:
  body1:
    fontFamily: "Roboto,"Helvetica Neue""
    fontSize: "1rem"
    fontWeight: 400
    lineHeight: 1.5
```

This is the setting I want. However to use that setting I have to use the `Typography` tag with `variant='body1'`. Otherwise, text inside a `div` has styling provided by `CssBaseline`. That's the rule on the `body` tag: `font-size: .875rem;` which I wish to override.

Do people override styling provided by CssBaseline by using createMuiTheme? If so, I added:

```
body: {
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
```

Which shows up on `console.log(theme)`, but how tell the `<body>` tag to actually use that style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of overriding this aspect of `CssBaseline`:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  "@global": {
    body: {
      ...theme.typography.body1
    }
  }
});

function MyCssBaseline() {
  return null;
}

MyCssBaseline.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyCssBaseline);
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import MyCssBaseline from "./MyCssBaseline";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <MyCssBaseline />
      <span>
        Here is some text in the body that is getting the body1 styling due to
        MyCssBaseline.
      </span>
    </>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

[image: Edit CssBaseline overrides]

Reference: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#global-css

Answer (score 0):

Thank [@RyanCogswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448538/using-createmuitheme-to-override-default-styles-on-divs-ps-body#answer-56450285). In MUI v5 write:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        h1 {
          color: grey;
        }
      `,
    },
  },
})
```

Or use `GlobalStyles` component. See:

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#4-global-css-override