# Using makeStyles - useStyles() globally throws 'Invalid Hook Call' error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, global

I get the 'Invalid hook error' using this example from Material UI's website:
https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#GlobalCss.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  '@global': {
    '.cssjss-advanced-global-root': {
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
    '.cssjss-advanced-global-child': {
      height: 8,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  },
});

export default function GlobalCss() {
  useStyles();   // <-- causes error

  return (
    <div className="cssjss-advanced-global-root">
      <div className="cssjss-advanced-global-child" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Material UI doesn't assign the "useStyles()" to a variable, they just call it inside the function component.

I, also need to call 'useStyles()' by itself to set global css.

Here is my package.json:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^3.0.0-alpha.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "css-object-loader": "0.0.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
```

**-------- FIXED --------**

I ended up using the GlobalCss as an exported module in my component library, as suggested.

But noticed there was a duplicate "react" instance, which caused the "Invalid Hook Error".

```
// run this to check for multiple instances
npm ls react
```

Here is how I told webpack to isolate the current "react" library being used:

```
// webpack.config.js 
resolve:{
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
    }
}
```

That fixed the error.

Comment: Please show the code of how you then use the `GlobalCss` component. You need to be rendering `GlobalCss` as a component -- not calling it as a function. My example here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448538/using-createmuitheme-to-override-default-styles-on-divs-ps-body/56450285#56450285

Comment: I decided to use GlobalCss separate based on your suggestion vs not inside my custom theme wrapper that's being exported as a library. Thank you! @RyanCogswell

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this with Material UI beta 0, and it made it try so many things.

First, ensure I have ONE version of React and React DOM, only.
I checked the versions by running:

```sh
npm ls react
npm ls react-dom
```

In my case, this didn't fix it.

I don't know if this is your error or not, but just to save other people googling like me, the issue in my case was that I needed to add `@material-ui/styles` as a dependency. The import was not complaining so I thought I didn't need to, but I did.

So, I did:

```sh
npm i @material-ui/styles@next
```

After many hours of messing with TypeScript and react-scripts versions and installing and reinstalling a lot of stuff - even thinking of installing some package that modifies the Webpack config of create-react-app to alias `react` properly, but none of that was needed, just the specific npm install, and it just worked!

By the way, you are supposed to have these in `dependencies` not `devDependencies` I think. Unless you are building a library on top of Material UI (not an app), and then they go to `peerDependencies`.