# How can I change Material UI's theme background color at breakpoints?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    body { background-color: red; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    body { background-color: blue; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body { background-color: green; }
}
```

And I have the following Material UI theme:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      background: {
        default: 'red'
      },
    }
});
```

I would like to replace the hard-coded CSS with breakpoints in the Material UI theme but I can't figure out how to do it.  I've tried the following (and several variations) and nothing seems to work.

```
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      background: {
        [defaultTheme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            default: 'red'
        }
      },
    }
});
```

Is this not supported by Material UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.5/packages/material-ui/src/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js#L17) how `theme.palette.background.default` is leveraged. The syntax you tried will just add a new property to `theme.palette.background` that Material-UI will never look at.

What you can do is create some custom entries in your theme such as the following:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      xs: "red",
      sm: "blue",
      md: "green"
    }
  }
});
```

and then use this in styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  "@global": {
    body: {
      [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.md
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.sm
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.xs
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit CssBaseline overrides]

Slightly related question: [Using createMuiTheme to override default styles on div's, p's, body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448538/using-createmuitheme-to-override-default-styles-on-divs-ps-body/56450285#56450285)